# Unable to parse headers from successful HTTP HEAD request in jquery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am using the following code to get file-size of a url, the debugger shows requests to be executed with **HTTP STATUS CODE 200** returning all headers including 'Content-Length' however my code outputting NULL values for headers (even after the request succeeded).

```
function checkURL(url) {
    try {
        var xhr = $.ajax({
            type: "HEAD",
            url: url,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                result = data;
            }
        });
        console.log('Size :' + xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length'));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('XHR Error :' + e);
    }
}
```

**EDIT # 1**

I tested the below code and it works, however not all headers are being displayed. Once again HTTP DEBUGGER shows the elusive 'Content-Length' header to be present in reply to this XHR.

```
function checkURL(url) {
try {
    var xhr = $.ajax({
            type : "HEAD",
            url : url,
            complete : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {

                console.log(XMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders());


            }

        });


} catch (e) {
    console.log('Check Size XHR Error :' + e);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats is your type HEAD ?
it must be a xml or json !

Comment: A HEAD request only fetches the headers which are being correctly pulled as shown in HTTP DEBUGGER, the file-type is BINARY.